# Android Project Application deployment Error from Archive Manager

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I follow the steps to deploy the android application from Archive manager of Visual studio 2015. The application is deployed second time.

Open Archive Manager -> Select Application -> Click on Distribute button -> Go for Google Play -> Import .keystore file for Signed Identity(which is already created for 1st deployment) -> continue -> Google Play Account -> Click on '+' -> Enter Client Id and Secret key and description ( which is already created) -> Click on Register -> It open up the web browser with Google play account and I click on 'Allow' -> It shows "Received verification code. You may now close this window".

However, after switching back to Visual Studio, I see this:
[image: Please see Image from here]

Please can anyone suggest me, why I am getting this error? and what am I doing wrong?
I am deploying android application first time but this application is already deployed and I did some changes and want to deploy.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have made a basic demo to reproduce this issue. You could check the ide log in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs`. In my case the detail of the exception is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

You need to download version 10 of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, and use `gacutil.exe` to install it in to GAC, as this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/313613/#Comment_313613) said.
You could find the `gacutil.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64` if your are using win10. And you could download `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` form [Newtonsoft.Json GitHub](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases).

For example, the command is:`gacutil.exe /i Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. The cmd should be run as administrator. And you may need to restart the vs.